# Add on touch listener for Firebase RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I tried to add an "on touch" listener to recyclerview with firebase but couldn't do it successfully. Can anyone help me?

```
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        DatabaseReference a = ref.child("ufile").child(unique_id).child("Files");

        final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<usersinfo,MessageViewHolder>adapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<usersinfo, MessageViewHolder>(usersinfo.class,android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,MessageViewHolder.class,a) {
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(MessageViewHolder viewHolder, usersinfo model, int position) {
                        viewHolder.mtext.setText(model.username);

                    }


                };

      rvdb.setAdapter(adapter);



    public  static class  MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
TextView mtext;
        public MessageViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

          mtext = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        }
    }
    public void retriveinfo(String username, String adress,String unique_id){
        DatabaseReference mDatabase;

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        usersinfo newuser= new usersinfo(username,adress);

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `populateViewHolder` you can add a click listener to the `ViewHolder` like this:

```
// itemView is a public field of all ViewHolder classes
viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // Your code here...
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it marks few errors on the coding. like "annotations are not allowed here"  " }"  ,")"  ",;" expected "  " Cannot resolve symbol v "

Comment: @APPBird oops I forgot some parentheses after `new View.OnClickListener`.  Added.